# How to validate google recaptcha in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: validation, magento2.3.1, google, recaptcha

I am using Magento version 2.3.1
I have enabled the google recaptcha module via backend & given the associated credentials.

Now captcha working fine in the registration page. But I wish to add a new button once captcha is verified.

How do I get the response or verify whether the captcha is verified in jQuery.

Please provide me a solution to check whether the captcha is verified or not.

> I have added i am not a bot captcha

Answer (score 0):

Googe recaptcha has a success event. You will need to utilise this to do something after.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31689541/10121426